# ... mit Texten siebener Autoren

Tags: numbers

Ich las soeben diesen Satz:

> Die Veranstaltung ist ein Beispiel dafür, wie man die Darbietung dreier Musiker mit Texten siebener Autoren verbindet.

Es geht dabei um die Deklination der Zahlwörter. Folgende Beispiele sind ja durchaus gängig:

> der Text **eines** Autors
>   die Texte **zweier** Autoren
>   die Texte **dreier** Autoren

Kann man dieses Schema weiterführen?

> die Texte **vierer** Autoren
>   die Texte **siebener** Autoren
>   die Texte **achtundzwanziger** Autoren

Denn das Folgende ist ja wieder korrekt, bedeutet aber nicht das, was es nach dem obigen Schema bedeuten sollte:

> die Texte **hunderter** Autoren
>   die Texte **tausender** Autoren

Comment: Ja, dieses Schema existiert so. Laut [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:vier) (als Beispiel) werden Zahlwörter genau so gebeugt.

Comment: Ich habe dazu eine Quelle gefunden, die vorigem Kommentar zustimmt, mit dem Zusatz, dass "[b]ei Zahlen ab vier [...] Gentivformen mit –er übrigens ungebräuchlich [sind]".  http://canoo.net/blog/2012/03/15/zahlen-im-genitiv/

Comment: Ich votiere dafür, die Frage **nicht** zu schließen, denn das allgemeine Bildungsschema ist ja eben nicht in beliebigen Nachschlagewerken zu finden. Eine Referenz auf einen Expertenbeitrag, in dem auch nur beiläufiger die Ungebräuchlichkeit erwähnt wird, zählt für mich nicht als Nachschlagewerk.

Comment: Bei 2 bis 4 Autoren ist das Schema durchaus gebäuchlich, aber bei 7 Autoren klingt das sehr ungewohnt. Ich würde das einfach umgehen und die Texte von sieben Autoren schreiben.

Comment: Siehe auch Ergänzungs-Edit meiner Antwort. (Ich glaube, über die Edits der Antworten wird man nicht benachrichtigt. Daher der Kommentar.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beides ist richtig.

Ja, die Bildung solcher Formen mit Zahlwörtern über "drei" ist ungebräuchlich.

Aber auch: Ja, in Textgattungen (oder Text-Orten), wo kreative Sprache erlaubt ist (oder wo man sich leisten kann, kreativ zu sein), spricht wenig gegen die Ausdehnung des Prinzips auf höhere Zahlen.

Übrigens meine ich mich an Stellen aus Literatur und Brauchtum zu erinnern, wo auch "vierer" vorkommt. (Wenn mir einfällt, wo das war, füge ich es noch an. Vielleicht war das bei Christoph Martin Wieland irgendwo... aber der ist ja auch sprachkreativ.)

Der Witz ist halt, dass man wissen muss, wo kreatives Formulieren angemessen ist und wo nicht.

Comment: Viererbob, der Deutschland-Achter?

Comment: @userunknown: Das was du meinst ist aber kein isolierter unbestimmter Genitiv, sondern ein Bestandteil eines Kompositums.

Answer (score 1):

Wenn man *will*, *kann* man dieses Schema natürlich weiterführen; mein Sprachgefühl gerät bei dem Satz mit **siebener** jedoch eindeutig ins Stocken.

Möglicherweise liegt der Grund für das Stocken darin, dass meine Sprachautomatik ein spezifischeres Schema bildet. Ausgehend von:

> **eines** Autors <-- korrekt, da völlig normale Flexion
>    **zweier** Autoren <-- als korrekt empfunden, da häufig im Gebrauch
>    **dreier** Autoren <-- als korrekt empfunden, da häufig im Gebrauch

scheint mein Sprachgefühl **zweier** und **dreier** nicht bloß zum Schema *Zahlwort*-**er** zu verallgemeinern, sondern spezifischer zu <*Zahlwort, das auf* **ei** *endet*>-**er** . Damit beginnt das Holpern schon bei **vierer**, da **vier** nicht auf **ei** endet.

Für **siebener** meldet mir mein Sprachgefühl ein "falsches Wort" zurück.

Für Zahlwörter, die auf /t/ oder /d/ enden, setzt bei mir dagegen das anders gemeinte Schema ein:

> **dutzender** Autoren
>    **hunderter** Autoren
>    **tausender** Autoren

Die Frage, was nun "richtig" sei, wird für den Leser/Hörer so einer Konstruktion wohl nicht von Interesse sein. Denn er wird sie nicht nach "richtig" oder "falsch", sondern nach dem unbewusst gebildeten Schema seines Sprachgefühls interpretieren und bewerten.

---

Wer nun, wie ein Kommentar zu dieser Antwort nahe legt, der Meinung ist, dass es willkürlich sei, ein Schema nur aus den zwei Fällen *zweier* und *dreier* zu bilden, *vierer* aber nicht mehr einzubeziehen, vergegenwärtige sich einfach mal die Häufigkeitsverhältnisse anhand von Google Books Ngram Viewer (exemplarisch zu den [**2000er**-Werten](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=zweier%2Cdreier%2Cvierer&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Czweier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdreier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvierer%3B%2Cc0) berechnet):

- Das Wort *dreier* wird knapp 7 Mal seltener verwendet als das Wort *zweier*.
- Das Wort *vierer* wird dagegen schon **96(!) Mal seltener** verwendet als das Wort *dreier*.

Es ist also schon ein gravierender "Riss" zwischen den Verwendungshäufigkeiten von *einer*, *zweier* und *dreier* auf der einen und *vierer*, *fünfer* etc. auf der anderen Seite.

Einen weiteren, aber bei weitem nicht so starken Häufigkeitsabsacker gibt es [von *vierer* zu *fünfer*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vierer%2Cf%C3%BCnfer%2Csechser%2Csiebener%2Cneuner&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvierer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cf%C3%BCnfer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csechser%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csiebener%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cneuner%3B%2Cc0) (hier wieder exemplarisch zu den **2000er**-Werten berechnet) - knapp 13 Mal seltener - , während die folgenden *sechser*, *siebener* und *neuner* sich alle mehr oder weniger in der gleichen Größenordnung wie *fünfer* bewegen - *siebener* etwa **1.470(!) Mal seltener** als *dreier*.

Bemerkenswert ist auch, dass [**alle** Google-Books-Fundstellen zu *siebener*](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22siebener%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1994,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_de&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=L1APWpLKNszWa4voqbgH) im Zeitraum 1994-2000 auf eine einzige Bildschirm-Seite passen. Eine Genitiv-Verwendung findet sich darunter nicht.

Die Genitiv-Verwendung findet man aber auch nicht mal mehr für *vierer*, wie wiederum dieses [Ngram-View für "zweier Menschen,dreier Menschen,vierer Menschen"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=zweier%20Menschen%2Cdreier%20Menschen%2Cvierer%20Menschen&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Czweier%20Menschen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdreier%20Menschen%3B%2Cc0) zeigt, und zwar **im ganzen Zeitraum von 1800 bis 2000**:

- "Ngrams not found: vierer Menschen"
- "Ngrams not found: vierer Personen"
- "Ngrams not found: vierer Autoren"

Comment: Probier mal "einer Autorin", um aus Deinem Ei-Schema zu schlüpfen.

Comment: @userunknown Ich verstehe den Hinweis nicht. Das Schema ist eben nicht auf "eines" oder "einer" aufgebaut, sondern auf "zweier" und "dreier".

Comment: Nur weil sich 2 auf 3 reimt von einem Schema zu sprechen ist aber gewagt. Mir ist kein Fall bekannt, wo man Endungen nach Reimen gruppieren kann. "Eines Autors" wird anders gebildet als "zweier, dreier, vierer Autoren", weil es Einzahl ist. Zwei Fälle, um eine Korrelation herzuleiten - kleiner kann das Sample ja kaum sein, wenn ein gemeinsames Merkmal abgeleitet werden soll. Das erste Gegenbeispiel "vierer" wird von Dir m.E. willkürlich ausgeschlossen, um zu diesem angeblichen Schema zu gelangen, für das es keine weiteren stützenden Argumente gibt. Das ist Esoterik, nicht kritische Analyse.

Comment: @userunknown Du verwechselst mehrere Dinge.a)Von Reim hat niemand was geschrieben; dass Vokal- und Konsonanten-Endungen der Wortwurzel in Sprachen zu verschiedenen Flexionen führen, ist dagegen eher die Regel als Ausnahme.b)Hier geht es nicht um Statistik, sondern darum, wie der Mensch sich die Sprache bildet. Schon von zwei Fällen ausgehend zu verallgemeinern, ist ein typisch-menschliches Verhalten; ob dieses Verhalten "berechtigt" ist, tut hier nichts zur Sache, denn Sprache ist menschen- und nicht natur-gemacht.c)Auch das im OP vorgeschlagene Schema basiert nur auf zwei Fällen.d)s.Edit.